# Showing computed and non-computed data in one column with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access database that has several tables. Of these tables, I have a bin table that shows 84 bins with the bin numbers being the primary key. It has another attribute for TotalCapacity. I have another table for inbound tickets that contains an attribute that accepts a number for bushels of commodity taken in. A third table has an attribute for bushels sent out.

```
SELECT BinNumber AS Bin, (TotalCapacity - SUM(BushelsIn) + SUM(BushelsOut)) AS SpaceRemaining
FROM T_BIN, T_INBOUND, T_OUTBOUND
WHERE T_BIN.BinNumber = T_INBOUND.BinNumber_FK AND T_BIN.BinNumber = T_OUTBOUND.BinNumber_FK
GROUP BY BinNumber, TotalCapacity;
```

This query works but only returns bins that have inbound or outbound tickets related to their bin number.

What I'm trying to do is get a list of all bins and their space available even if their total capacity is unchanged. I've tried every combination I can think of but I'm relatively new to SQL commands and can't seem to find the right way to go about this.

Comment: Can you please provide some of the samples you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `LEFT JOIN`.  In MS Access, I think this looks like:

```
SELECT B.BinNumber AS Bin,
       (TotalCapacity - NZ(SUM(BushelsIn), 0) + NZ(SUM(BushelsOut), 0)
       ) AS SpaceRemaining
FROM (T_BIN AS B LEFT JOIN
      T_INBOUND AS I
      ON B.BinNumber = I.BinNumber_FK
     ) LEFT JOIN
     T_OUTBOUND AS O
     ON B.BinNumber = O.BinNumber_FK
GROUP BY B.BinNumber, B.TotalCapacity;
```

This introduces table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

The `NZ()` function converts `NULL` values to `0`, so the `SUM()` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is `left join`. But you need to add first your `BushelsIn` and `BushelsOut` before your deduct to your `TotalCapacity`.

```
select BinNumber as Bin
    , max(TotalCapacity) - (sum(BushelsIn) + sum(BushelsOut)) as SpaceRemaining 
from T_BIN t1
left join T_INBOUND t2 on t1.BinNumber = t2.BinNumber_FK 
left join T_OUTBOUND t3 on t1.BinNumber = t3.BinNumber_FK 
group by BinNumber;
```